# Worklight project can not build on IOS SDK 8.0 environment

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, ios8, worklight-studio

I'm using Xcode command-line to automate app builds. As part of my script I use "xcodebuild -list" to parse the target name. It works fine with SDK's 6.1, 7.0, 7.1 but it has stopped working for SDK 8.0 Beta which will get time out. As background information, my xcode project is generated by Worklight, which by default targets SDK 5.0, it seems SDK 8.0 is not compatible with SDK 5.0. Therefore, I wonder if this is a SDK 8.0 compatibility issue, or worklight should update the default SDK to be higher version.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 support will be dropped in a future Worklight release (the minimum will be iOS 6).

For current releases (5.x - 6.2) if you'd like to use Xcode 6's command line tools, you will need to manually alter the deployment target in the Xcode project's Build Settings section.

Comment: Hi Idan, Thanks for your answer. Here is one more question, if you know when Worklight will drop iOS 5?

Comment: I cannot answer such questions obviously. Near future.